# owncloud installation client error

Tags: owncloud

When I visit our OwnCloud installation, I'm seeing the following error message:

PHP PDO module is not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

Is there anyone have an Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If this module is listened there it doesn't mean that it is loaded / activated.

So you or your hoster should check that the modules (pdo and pdo_mysql for example) is loaded in your php.ini."